# Правильно составлено ли это предложение?

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление, падежи, предлоги

В данной выпускной работе анализируются методы обеспечение безопасности веб сайтов. Помимо этого, структуре веб сайтов, существующих уязвимости в этом анализируются, предложена методы обеспечение безопасности с помощью существующих механизмов, устроив  атака на основе уязвимость маленького веб сайта.

In this graduation work, methods of ensuring Web sites security are analyzed. And also, structure of Web sites, existing vulnerabilities in it, attacked on the basis of vulnerability of small web site and proposed methods  of ensuring security of Web site using existing mechanisms.

Comment: this is not a translation service. Please, modify the question to make it less look like a pure translation request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет.
Честно говоря, я даже не понимаю о чем идет речь.

Правильный вариант первого предложения:

> В данной выпускной работе анализируются методы обеспечени**я** безопасности веб-сайтов.

And the rest, according to the English text:

> В частности, анализируется структура веб-сайта и его уязвимости путем атаки, основанной на уязвимости небольшого веб-сайта, а также предлагаются методы обеспечения безопасности веб-сайта с использованием существующих механизмов.